# Google analytics experiment redirect

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, settings, tracking, google-experiments

Hi I have an issue with experiments.

This is my original page: http://cellulem.netlogiq.com/test1.html

and the variations 1: http://cellulem.netlogiq.com/test2.html

The problem is when I access the test1.html page, it redirected me always on the same page, after a few seconds.

I inserted the experiment code right after the head tag, and after that the tracking code. 
so any ideas why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like expected behaviour. The experiment redirects you to the same page because recurring visitors need to see the same page for every pageview/visits (it would confuse the heck out of your visitors were they to see different pages for every pageview, plus it would ruin your experiment).

Try and delete your cookies between reloads so the Google does not recognize you as recurring visitor. Try at least ten reloads (the code redirects randomly, not alternating - it's not unusual to get the same page four or five times in a row if you just have one variation).

Updated to include the discussion from the comments:

The experiment code only goes into the original page (else there will be unwanted redirects on other pages). If you have a common header in your template you could check if you are on the original page by inspecting the current url, like so:

```
if(window.location.href === 'original.html ') { 
// display experiment code 
}
```

Comment: thx for responding me, I really appreciate it and it works, but I got stuck with another problem. when the GA redirects you in the varions page, after that when users clicks on another page( let say contact page), it will redirected always on the varions page. Is this normal to happen ??? I have to mentioned the tracking code is included only on the original and varion page .

Comment: No. Most probably you inserted the experiment code in all pages, it's supposed to go only in the original page.

Comment: I just edited my previous comment and i mentioned that the tracking code is included only on the original and varion page.

Comment: this is the original page : http://www.cellulemblock.ro/epilare-definitiva-ipl-laser.html and this is the varions page http://www.cellulemblock.ro/Epilare-Definitiva.html. As u can see if u go to "Despre Noi" page in the main menu, before accesing the original page, there is no tracking code installed

Comment: Actually I see code in both pages (I'm not talking about tracking code but the experiment code that does the redirect  and starts with the comment < !-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -- > - this is doing the redirect, so you don't want it in all pages, just where the redirect is supposed to happen.

Comment: so I put the experiment code, in the original page , or in the variations page ?

Comment: In the original only.

Comment: the problem is that i have a header , which are included in all pages. And the experiment code has to be inserted in the head tag. If i not inserted in the head tag, I got an infinite loop. So any ideas?

Comment: Some conditional to check if the visitor is on the original page might work: if(window.location.href === 'http://www.cellulemblock.ro/epilare-definitiva-ipl-laser.html ') {

 // display experiment code

}

Comment: Hi, if this turns out to work could you accept my anwser (stackexchange  assigns "reputation" points based on helpful/accepted answers) ?

Comment: At the top of my anwser at the left side you should see a checkmark that you can click to accept the answer. Here is a link that explains what accepting is for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work